# Algebra problem about sale and regular price

Tags: economics, percentages

Can you please help me solve this problem?

> The sale price on a new natural gas furnace is $\$2750$. This represents $12\%$ off the regular price. What is the regular price?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x-.12x=2750$$
$$.88x=2750$$
$$x=2750/.88$$
$$x = 3125$$

Comment: What is the point of asking the OP what they have tried if you are just going to provide the answer?

Comment: So the question doesn't remain unanswered... Knowing this community it most likely would

Comment: Thank you N.Bar for your answer ! This is corrrect